# proof that integral of odd function is even function

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

let $F:\Bbb R \to\Bbb R$ and $F'= f$ .

given that $f$ is odd, prove that $F$ is even,

my attempt :

1. $(F(-x))' = -f(x)$
2. $f(x)= \frac{f(x) + f(x)}{2} = \frac{f(x) - f(-x)}{2}$ , because f is odd

$\Rightarrow F(x) = \int f(x)dx = \int\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}=\frac{F(x)}{2}+\frac{F(-x)}{2}$

$\Rightarrow F(x) = F(-x)\Rightarrow F$ is even

is there is any mistake in this proof ?

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Looks good enough

Comment: Maybe add a +C after you've evaluated the indefinite integral, so F(x)=...+C for some fixed value of C, and its easy to then justify that C=0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should proceed directly using derivatives and not integrals (because indefinite integrals are not unique). Let us consider the function $g(x) = F(x) - F(-x)$ so that $$g'(x) = F'(x) + F'(-x) = f(x) + f(-x) = 0$$ Thus $g(x)$ is a constant and then $g(x) = g(0) = F(0) - F(0) = 0$ so that $F(x) = F(-x)$ for all $x$. Thus $F$ is an even function.

Note that the cousin result is false:

*If $F' = f$ and $f$ is even then $F$ is odd.*

A simple counter-example is $F(x) = x + 1$ and $f(x) = 1$ so that $f$ is even and yet $F$ is neither even nor odd. It can be made true by adding that $F(0) = 0$. Thus we have the following result which is correct.

*If $F' = f, F(0) = 0$ and $f$ is even then $F$ is odd.*

Comment: is there is any way that i can avoid that the indefinite integral are not unique ?

Comment: Indefinite integrals are "indefinite" ie not unique that's why they are named so. So I gave this approach which avoids the issue with integrals.

Answer (score 3):

Since $F'(x)=f(x)$, one has
$$ F(x)=\int_0^xf(s)ds. $$
Under $t=-s$, one has
$$ F(-x)=\int_0^{-x}f(s)ds=-\int_0^xf(-t)dt. $$
Now $f(x)$ is odd and hence $f(-x)=-f(x)$. So
$$ F(-x)=\int_0^{-x}f(s)ds=-\int_0^xf(-t)dt=\int_0^xf(t)dt=F(x) $$
and $F(x)$ is even.